# Applications not showing properly after clicking 'show application'

Tags: gnome, screen, 20.10, touchscreen, button

I think the screen is not refreshing

[image]

Comment: You have graphical glitches. Include info on your hardware `sudo lshw -c display` and current kernel `uname -a`.